# Are nonzero eigenvalues of $A*B$ and $pinv(A)*A*B*A$ identical?

Tags: linear-algebra

Are the nonzero eigenvalues of matrix products $AB$ and $A^+ABA$ identical? If so, kindly furnish a proof. Further, although the eigenvalues are identical, can they turn out to be slightly different due to numerical rounding off?

Note $A$ is a matrix of order $m \times n$, $B$ is a matrix of order $n \times m$ where $m > n$, and $A^+$ denotes the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse.

Moreover, does the conclusion drawn above also hold for the matrix products $AB$ and $C^+ABC$ where $C$ is a general $m \times n$ matrix?

Comment: What is "pinv(A)"?

Comment: pinv stands for pseudoinverse in general and Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse in particular. Further, the matrices A, B and C above are real.

Answer (score 1):

**Fact.** Suppose that $X$ is $m\times n$ and that $Y$ is $n\times m$. Then the characteristic polynomials of $XY$ and $YX$ satisfy $\chi_{YX}(t)=t^{n-m}\cdot\chi_{XY}(t)$. In particular, $XY$ and $YX$ have the same nonzero eigenvalues.

Now, take $X=A^+A$ and $Y=BA$. Then
\begin{align*}
XY &= A^+ABA & YX &= BAA^+A=BA
\end{align*}
have the same eigenvalues. Since $AB$ and $BA$ have the same eigenvalues, it follows that $A^+ABA$ and $AB$ have the same eigenvalues.

To address your last question, I don't see any reason that the eigenvalues of $AB$ and $C^+ABC$ would coincide. Indeed, consider
\begin{align*}
A &= \left[\begin{array}{rrr}
-1 & -1 & -3 \\
-2 & -2 & -6
\end{array}\right] & B &= \left[\begin{array}{rr}
0 & 0 \\
-5 & 5 \\
1 & -1
\end{array}\right] & C &= \left[\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 1 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]
\end{align*}
Then 
\begin{align*}
AB &= \left[\begin{array}{rr}
2 & -2 \\
4 & -4
\end{array}\right] & C^+ABC &= \left[\begin{array}{rrr}
\frac{2}{3} & \frac{2}{3} & -\frac{2}{3} \\
\frac{2}{3} & \frac{2}{3} & -\frac{2}{3} \\
-\frac{2}{3} & -\frac{2}{3} & \frac{2}{3}
\end{array}\right]
\end{align*}
Can you compute these eigenvalues?

Comment: Thank you very much. What about the second part of my question? Does this conclusion apply to (A*B) and (pinv(C)*A*B*C) where C is a general m X n matrix?

Comment: I don't see any obvious relation between these eigenvalues. See my updated answer for an example.

Comment: Thank you again.